# (HTML/CSS) Trying to get text to be aligned at the top of page - yet on opposite sides

Tags: html, css, navbar, text-alignment

I'm looking for a way to raise text up so that it can mirror the other text that is on the top left portion of the webpage.

I have text that is centered perfectly on the top left portion of my navbar. I have other text that has appeared on the top right potion of my page - semi near the navbar. I am looking for a way to raise the portion of text up so that it is level with the text in the top left portion, while keeping its placement in the top right area of the webpage.

The **h3** element text is in perfect placement (top left)
The text in the **div** elements under the "navbar-right" class is centered to the top right of the webpage - which is correct- but it is not level with the text in **h3** element.

Literally any help with this would be awesome. Thank you.
I tried looking around, yet couldn't find an exact answer. Hoping for any help or advice.

~ HTML ~ :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="cleanstyle.css" />
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/d7e8a95865396cddca89b00080d2cba6?family=SoDo+Sans+SemiBold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="navbar">
    <h3>Example</h3>
</div>
    <div class="navbar-left"></div>
    <div class="navbar-right">
        <div>Home</div>
        <div>About</div>
        <div>Portfolio</div>
        <div>Contact</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

~ CSS ~ :

```
@import url(//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/d7e8a95865396cddca89b00080d2cba6?family=SoDo+Sans+SemiBold);

body {
   margin: 0px;
   font-family: "SoDo Sans SemiBold",Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-right {
    justify-content: right;
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: right;
}

h3 {
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar-left div {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-left,
.navbar-right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-left > *,
.navbar-right > * {
    margin: 10px;
}

li {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may set the `.navbar` as a parent element to both `.navbar-left` and `.navbar-right` with `display:flex` and `justify-content: space-between`.

Your `<h3>` will be under the `.navbar-left`, and navigation div elements will under the `.navbar-right`

```css
@import url(//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/d7e8a95865396cddca89b00080d2cba6?family=SoDo+Sans+SemiBold);

body {
   margin: 0px;
   font-family: "SoDo Sans SemiBold",Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar-right {
    justify-content: right;
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: right;
}

h3 {
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar-left h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-left,
.navbar-right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-left > *,
.navbar-right > * {
    margin: 10px;
}

li {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="cleanstyle.css" />
      <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/d7e8a95865396cddca89b00080d2cba6?family=SoDo+Sans+SemiBold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-left">
        <h3>Example</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-right">
        <div>Home</div>
        <div>About</div>
        <div>Portfolio</div>
        <div>Contact</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```